# How to use milliseconds in FFmpeg's drawText?

Tags: ffmpeg, milliseconds

How can I use milliseconds to define the placement of text?

```
drawtext=fontfile=font/arial.ttf:text='Test':enable='between(t,1,5)'
```

Currently, I only have the option of seconds using the [enable command](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use "between(n, start_frame, end_frame)" instead,  start_frame = start_time * r, end_frame = end_time * r;

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use decimal numbers. Something like:

```
drawtext=fontfile=font/arial.ttf:text='Test':enable='between(t\,1.423,5.550)'
```